# Search for a value in all fields while having an existing filter in Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I have the following filter in Cloud Logging that shows me all logs from a particular instance:

```
(resource.type="gce_instance" AND resource.labels.instance_id="***") OR (resource.type="global" AND jsonPayload.instance.id="***")
```

In this set, I want to search for a value in all fields. By looking at the documentation https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#searching-examples I found that I can write a simple word `unicorn` in the query fields and it will search in all fields. It works, but it searches in all my logs. But I want to search in the filtered logs set only, not across all logs in Cloud Logging. I want to get all rows containing the word `failed` and tried this:

```
((resource.type="gce_instance" AND resource.labels.instance_id="***") OR (resource.type="global" AND jsonPayload.instance.id="***")) and failed
```

But id doesn't work. How can I search in all fields while already having a filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the query formatting this way the last part:

```
((resource.type="gce_instance" AND resource.labels.instance_id="***") OR 
(resource.type="global" AND jsonPayload.instance.id="***")) AND "failed"
```

Cheers,